# Are there any tools for categorizing the project?

Tags: project-management-style

I mean like small, medium and larger project. I have seen in some places the following could be factors for determining the project:

- Scope
- Time/Schedule
- Cost/Budget
- Resources

Are there any tools to determine what type of project it is?

Comment: Are you looking for software, or a set of rules?

Comment: Completely depends on your environment.  Halliburton has a different definition of "large" than my local PTA.

Answer (score 1):

In the official PRINCE2 Manual (i.e. "Managing Successful projects with PRINCE2"), there is a chapter (no. 19) on tailoring the PRINCE2 method to the project environment.

One of the factors described in there is the project scale, i.e. how big or how small is the project (measured in terms of time, cost, resources...), how complex is it, the level of risk...
It also includes some (examples of) characteristics for the different scales:

- Simple project: low risk, cost, importance, visibility. A single organization and a single site.
- Normal project: medium risk, cost, importance, visibility. A commercial customer/supplier relationship. Multiple sites.
- ...

These are just examples of what could be characteristics. The manual gives some guidance on how to apply PRINCE2 to these different types of projects.
It's definitely not the most elaborate section, but gives you some suggestions.

If you have access to the PRINCE2 manual, it's section 19.5 and table 19.2 I'm referring to.

Here are some more pointers to information:

- [Using Project Scale In A PRINCE2 Project](http://www.prince2primer.com/using-project-scale-in-a-prince2-project/) and [Project Scale – a key PRINCE2 tailoring factor](http://www.prince2primer.com/prince2-project-scale/)
- The white paper from AXELOS: [PRINCE2 for small-scale projects](https://www.axelos.com/case-studies-and-white-papers/prince2-for-small-scale-projects) (Requires registration, but is free. Don't be misled by the titel of the whitepaper in the web version. It refers to MSP, but seems to be wrong to me. It has the right content. You can also download a pdf version, that one has the right title.)

All of these look at project scale from a PRINCE2 perspective obviously!